# Can you hide attribute columns in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

How can I hide some columns in a QGIS table while I am working on it so that I don't need to scroll so far to the left or right when I have a large number of attributes? Something like Excel does for spreadsheets.

Comment: please mark the answer that you think is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For QGIS 3 the same process is a little bit different. Setup of columns visibility should be done in Layer properties - Attributes form. The explicit manual is [here](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#attributes-form-properties).

Answer (score 14):

In QGIS 3.16 onwards: In the attribute table, right click on the column name, then press `Hide Column`

OR

Above the column names in the opened attribute table, click on "Organize Columns" and remove the tick from the checkbox(es) - this is also the way to show the hidden columns again.

Comment: I'm using version 2.14.4

Comment: Hide column can be done starting from QGIS 2.16 and above https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog216/index.html

Answer (score 5):

Using QGIS 2.14, please select your layer and right-click your mouse, open **Properties**. On Layer Properties window, push **Text Edit** button of your target field, under **Edit Widget**.

By selecting **Hidden**, your column will be invisible.

[image]

NOTE: Please do not **Hide** your column if you are using other **Widget** function, such as **Value Map**. When you set "Hidden", your Value Map setting will be erased...

Comment: If you hide the column using the right click method AND have it hidden in the widget field, then decide to unhide using the right click, you will not be able to click and edit that column. You will only be able to edit using the field calculator. If you want to click to edit, you need to go back to the Fields area and change the widget back to Text Edit.

Comment: @Johanna Which QGIS version are you working on now?

Comment: I am on 2.18 at the moment.

Comment: @Johanna Thanks. I understand these two cannot getting along with each other. Would you like to report this finding as issue / enhancement proposal to developers?