# Hide many attribute columns in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I know this is pretty much a duplicate of [Can you hide attribute columns in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219755/can-you-hide-attribute-columns-in-qgis/219758) but I have about 100 columns I want to hide so right clicking each column - Hide is not ideal.

Isn't there a way to hide many columns, then unhide the ones I want to see, like this in ArcMap:
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right click on a column name, as you do to hide a single column, but choose "Organize Columns..." instead.

Click "Deselect All" (The *Select All* and *Deselect All* buttons only appear if you have a lot of columns, otherwise you have to untick them individually).

**IMPORTANT:** Tick at least one column back on.

Click OK.

If you don't tick one column back on then you can not get any columns back:

[How to show hidden columns in QGIS 3.6.1 (?)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318348/how-to-show-hidden-columns-in-qgis-3-6-1)

At least until the fix is live:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/33918

Update:

Fix has been merged into Master, so should be in the next version of QGIS 3.14. Should be backported into 3.10 LTR, and possibly 3.12.